# How to bind kendo combo in kenod grid based on Id

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am binding kendo combo in kendo grid. Combo should bind dynamically based on item code from adjacent column. I have written below code. Combo does not bind.

```
$("#DieItemGrid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        data: result,
                        autoSync: true,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: 'ParentItemId',
                                fields: {
                                    ParentItemCd: { type: "string", nullable: false },
                                    ChildItemCd: { editable: false }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    columns:
                        [
                        {
                            field: "ChildItemCd",
                            title: "Die Item Code",
                            headerAttributes: {
                                style: "vertical-align: middle;"
                            }

                        },
                         {
                             field: "InternalRevDatalist", title: parentItemCd + "<br>Int. Rev Step",
                             editor:
                              function (container, options) {
                                  $.FwAJAX({
                                      showBusyIndicator: false,
                                      url: $.FwRoute.Base() + "GetInternalRevStepList",
                                      data: { itemCd: "#=ChildItemCd#" },//not able to get this id
                                      //data: {itemCd: '10036064'},
                                      dataType: 'json',
                                      success: function (result) {
                                          $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                                              .appendTo(container)
                                              .kendoComboBox({
                                                  autoBind: false,
                                                  dataTextField: "Description",
                                                  dataValueField: "FriendlyId",
                                                  placeholder: "-- Select --",
                                                  dataSource: result,
                                                  change: function (e) {
                                                      e.preventDefault();
                                                    //onchange
                                                  }
                                              });
                                      }
                                  });


                              }
                             , template: dieinternalRevListTemplate

                         }
                        ],

                    dataBound: function () {
                        var dataView = this.dataSource.view();
                        for (var i = 0; i < dataView.length; i++) {
                            var uid = dataView[i].uid;
                            $("#DieItemGrid tbody").find("tr[data-uid=" + uid + "]").addClass("datadisable");
                        }
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    selectable: "multiple cell",
                });
```

[image]

I am not able to get ChildItemCd. Based on this id I need to fill combobox.

Comment: You are trying to get the childItemId event before the data is bound to the grid, hence its blank. You need to let the grid load first and then bind the combo box, probably on select row event or probably after databound, call function to set datasource of the combobox with respective columns value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `options` argument, you have a property called `model`, which is the model of the current row.

Use it like:

```
data: { itemCd: options.model.ChildItemCd }
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AjOFU)

Comment: You are awesome @DontVoteMeDown. Thank you. It worked. :)

Comment: @RajeshBiswas great! glad to help.